# How should I do when different user-set CMake configuration options clash?

Tags: cmake, user-interaction, buildconfiguration

Suppose I have two cached CMake strings for the user to set, but some of the value combinations clash.

Example:

```
set(FOO OFF CACHE BOOL "Foo")
set(BAR OFF CACHE BOOL "Bar")
```

but you can't have both Foo and Bar.

Obviously, we can prevent this with:

```
if (FOO AND BAR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Can't have both Foo and Bar.")
endif()
```

but is there some other mechanism? e.g. something which, in ccmake, would make the value of BAR revert to false if FOO is set to true and vice-versa?

Note: This is a simplified example. In the simple case one could just opt for a single tri-state option, but that wouldn't work when you have multiple possible values and  a somewhat more complex forbidden-combination predicate.

Comment: Would `CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION` be of any help?

Comment: @vre: Oh, yes! Please make this an answer...

Comment: "would make the value of BAR revert to false if FOO is set to true and vice-versa?" - Given case could be more expressed in more natural form with a **single** *tristate* parameter. `set(FEATURE "None" CACHE STRING "Could be 'Foo', 'Bar' or 'None'")`. Using [STRINGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_cache/STRINGS.html) property you may set a list of possible values for CMake GUI.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Actually, my case is more complicated, I only simplified it for the example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmake_dependent_option` can be used for this purpose, it sets an option based on another set of variables being true.

For example,

```
cmake_option(FOO "Use Foo" ON)
cmake_dependent_option(BAR "Use Bar" ON "NOT FOO" OFF)
```

For further information see CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeDependentOption.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `set`'s `FORCE` option to force-set a CMake cache variable value.

```
if (FOO)
  set(BAR OFF CACHE BOOL "Bar" FORCE)
elseif (BAR)
  set(FOO OFF CACHE BOOL "Foo" FORCE)
endif()
```

This will be reflected in the GUI after the next Configure pass.

Comment: Do I have these lines in addition to my own, or instead of them?

Comment: Additionally to the initial cache variable declaration. Nevertheless, @vre's answer will probably better suit your use case.